# Update Azure AD/Entra ID directory role settings using the Microsoft Graph PoweShell module

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-entra-id

I'm attempting to write code to set Azure AD/Entra ID directory role settings using the Microsoft Graph PoweShell, e.g. whether MFA or a justification is required.

Here is my code:

```
#Enable script logging. $logFilePath = "C:\Code\scripts\logs\entraidsetdirectoryrolesettings-$(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss").log" Start-Transcript -Path $logFilePath -Append

Connect-MgGraph -Scopes "RoleManagement.ReadWrite.Directory" -NoWelcome

Import-Module "C:\Code\scripts\entraid\entraidallprivilegeddirectoryroles.ps1" $privilegedroleIds = $global:privilegedroleIds

Import-Module "C:\Code\scripts\entraid\entraiddirectoryrolesconfig.ps1" $privilegedroleSettings = $global:privilegedroleSettings $nonprivilegedroleSettings = $global:nonprivilegedroleSettings

$roleDefinitions = Get-MgRoleManagementDirectoryRoleDefinition

Write-Output "Retrieved '$($roleDefinitions.Count)' directory roles from the module:" foreach ($roleDefinition in $roleDefinitions) { Write-Output "- $($roleDefinition.DisplayName) (ID: $($roleDefinition.Id))" }

foreach ($roleDefinition in $roleDefinitions) { Check if the role is privileged based on its role definition id if ($roleDefinition.Id -in $privilegedroleIds) { Apply the activation settings for privileged roles. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id  ActivationMaximumDurationInHours = $privilegedroleSettings['activationMaximumDurationInHoursPriv'] RequireMfaOnActivation = $privilegedroleSettings['requireMfaOnActivationPriv'] RequireJustificationOnActivation = $privilegedroleSettings['requireJustificationOnActivationPriv'] RequireTicketInformationOnActivation = $privilegedroleSettings['requireTicketInformationOnActivationPriv'] RequireApprovalToActivate = $privilegedroleSettings['requireApprovalToActivatePriv']

Apply the assignment settings for privileged roles. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id AllowPermanentEligibleAssignment = $privilegedroleSettings['allowPermanentEligibleAssignmentPriv'] AllowPermanentActiveAssignment = $privilegedroleSettings['allowPermanentActiveAssignmentPriv'] RequireMfaOnActiveAssignment = $privilegedroleSettings['requireMfaOnActiveAssignmentPriv'] RequireJustificationOnActiveAssignment = $privilegedroleSettings['requireJustificationOnActiveAssignmentPriv']

Apply the alerting settings for privileged roles. Send notifications when members are assigned as eligible to this role. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id 
        -RoleAssignmentAlertDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleDefaultRecipientsPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertAssignedUserNotificationDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleAssignedUserNotificationDefaultRecipientsPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertApproverNotificationDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleApproverNotificationDefaultRecipientsPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertCriticalEmailsOnly = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleCriticalEmailsOnlyPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertAssignedUserNotificationCriticalEmailsOnly = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleAssignedUserNotificationCriticalEmailsOnlyPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertApproverNotificationCriticalEmailsOnly = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleApproverNotificationCriticalEmailsOnlyPriv']

Send notifications when members are assigned as active to this role. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id
        -RoleAssignmentAlertDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveDefaultRecipientsPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertAssignedUserNotificationDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveAssignedUserNotificationDefaultRecipientsPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertApproverNotificationDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveApproverNotificationDefaultRecipientsPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertCriticalEmailsOnly = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveCriticalEmailsOnlyPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertAssignedUserNotificationCriticalEmailsOnly = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveAssignedUserNotificationCriticalEmailsOnlyPriv']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertApproverNotificationCriticalEmailsOnly = $privilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveApproverNotificationCriticalEmailsOnlyPriv']

Send notifications when eligible members activate this role. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id
        -RoleActivationAlertDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleActivationAlertDefaultRecipientsPriv']
        -RoleActivationAlertCriticalEmailsOnly = $privilegedroleSettings['roleActivationAlertCriticalEmailsOnlyPriv']
        -RoleActivationAlertActivatedUserNotificationDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleActivationAlertActivatedUserNotificationDefaultRecipientsPriv']
        -RoleActivationAlertApproverNotificationDefaultRecipients = $privilegedroleSettings['roleActivationAlertApproverNotificationDefaultRecipientsPriv']

else { Apply the activation settings for non-privileged roles. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id 
        -ActivationMaximumDurationInHours = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['activationMaximumDurationInHoursStd']
        -RequireMfaOnActivation = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireMfaOnActivationStd']
        -RequireJustificationOnActivation = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireJustificationOnActivationStd']
        -RequireTicketInformationOnActivation = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireTicketInformationOnActivationStd']
        -RequireApprovalToActivate = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireApprovalToActivateStd']

Apply the assignment settings for privileged roles. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id
        -AllowPermanentEligibleAssignment = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['allowPermanentEligibleAssignmentStd']
        -AllowPermanentActiveAssignment = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['allowPermanentActiveAssignmentStd']
        -RequireMfaOnActiveAssignment = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireMfaOnActiveAssignmentStd']
        -RequireJustificationOnActiveAssignment = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireJustificationOnActiveAssignmentStd']

Apply the alerting settings for privileged roles. Send notifications when members are assigned as eligible to this role. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id 
        -RoleAssignmentAlertDefaultRecipients = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleDefaultRecipientsStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertAssignedUserNotificationDefaultRecipients = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleAssignedUserNotificationDefaultRecipientsStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertApproverNotificationDefaultRecipients = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleApproverNotificationDefaultRecipientsStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertCriticalEmailsOnly = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleCriticalEmailsOnlyStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertAssignedUserNotificationCriticalEmailsOnly = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleAssignedUserNotificationCriticalEmailsOnlyStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertApproverNotificationCriticalEmailsOnly = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertEligibleApproverNotificationCriticalEmailsOnlyStd']

Send notifications when members are assigned as active to this role. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id
        -RoleAssignmentAlertDefaultRecipients = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentActiveAlertDefaultRecipientsStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertAssignedUserNotificationDefaultRecipients = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveAssignedUserNotificationDefaultRecipientsStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertApproverNotificationDefaultRecipients = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveApproverNotificationDefaultRecipientsStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertCriticalEmailsOnly = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveCriticalEmailsOnlyStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertAssignedUserNotificationCriticalEmailsOnly = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveAssignedUserNotificationCriticalEmailsOnlyStd']
        -RoleAssignmentAlertApproverNotificationCriticalEmailsOnly = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleAssignmentAlertActiveApproverNotificationCriticalEmailsOnlyStd']

Send notifications when eligible members activate this role. Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id
        -RoleActivationAlertDefaultRecipients = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleActivationAlertDefaultRecipientsStd']
        -RoleActivationAlertCriticalEmailsOnly = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleActivationAlertCriticalEmailsOnlyStd']
        -RoleActivationAlertActivatedUserNotificationDefaultRecipients = $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleActivationAlertActivatedUserNotificationDefaultRecipientsStd']
        -RoleActivationAlertApproverNotificationDefaultRecipients $nonprivilegedroleSettings['roleActivationAlertApproverNotificationDefaultRecipientsStd']
    } }

Disconnect-MgGraph

Stop-Transcript
```

I am expecting these settings to be configued as per the settings in this script.

Answer (score 0):

This is an modifoed code im juz assuming that the parameters used in Update-MgDirectoryRole are accurate, check if its accurate

```html
# ... (your existing code)

foreach ($roleDefinition in $roleDefinitions) {
    # Check if the role is privileged based on its role definition id
    if ($roleDefinition.Id -in $privilegedroleIds) {
        # Apply the activation settings for privileged roles
        Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id `
            -ActivationMaximumDurationInHours $privilegedroleSettings['activationMaximumDurationInHoursPriv'] `
            -RequireMfaOnActivation $privilegedroleSettings['requireMfaOnActivationPriv'] `
            -RequireJustificationOnActivation $privilegedroleSettings['requireJustificationOnActivationPriv'] `
            -RequireTicketInformationOnActivation $privilegedroleSettings['requireTicketInformationOnActivationPriv'] `
            -RequireApprovalToActivate $privilegedroleSettings['requireApprovalToActivatePriv']

        # ... (similar updates for assignment and alerting settings)

    } else {
        # Apply the activation settings for non-privileged roles
        Update-MgDirectoryRole -Id $roleDefinition.Id `
            -ActivationMaximumDurationInHours $nonprivilegedroleSettings['activationMaximumDurationInHoursStd'] `
            -RequireMfaOnActivation $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireMfaOnActivationStd'] `
            -RequireJustificationOnActivation $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireJustificationOnActivationStd'] `
            -RequireTicketInformationOnActivation $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireTicketInformationOnActivationStd'] `
            -RequireApprovalToActivate $nonprivilegedroleSettings['requireApprovalToActivateStd']

        # ... (similar updates for assignment and alerting settings)
    }
}

# ... (your remaining code)

Disconnect-MgGraph
Stop-Transcript
```